# how to apply two serializers in one action in rails 5?

Tags: active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want to serialize incoming_requests and outgoing_requests with a few column values with customized name.
Without serializer, I wrote codes like below.

```
def index
  incoming_requests = FriendRequest.select('id', 'user_id', 'created_at').where(:friend => current_user).order(created_at: :desc)
  outgoing_requests = current_user.friend_requests.select('id', 'friend_id', 'created_at')

  render json: {
  incoming_requests: incoming_requests, 
  outgoing_requests: outgoing_requests
  }    
end
```

However, I want to replace 'select' with serializers. After applying serializers on the output for the codes below, I want to achieve the same result as the result from the above codes.

```
def index
  incoming_requests = FriendRequest.where(:friend => current_user).order(created_at: :desc)
  outgoing_requests = current_user.friend_requests

  render json: {
  incoming_requests: incoming_requests, // want to apply serializer
  outgoing_requests: outgoing_requests  // want to apply serializer
  }    
end
```

So, how can I serialize these incoming and outgoing request objects seperately?

Comment: At the end, I decided to use as_json to serialize those two requests in one action.